# Infinite sum over even indexs

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Claim:
>   $\sum_{m}^{\infty}\binom{2m}{m}p^{m}q^{m}\approx\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}$ 
>   $\frac{\left ( 4pq \right )^{m}}{\left ( \pi m \right )^{1/2}}$

This claim appear in my text without show of proof.

Any help with proving this claim is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stirling's formula.

Comment: Do you know that there is a very simple closed form of the infinite summation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a_m=\binom{2 m}{m}=\frac{(2m)!}{(n!)^2}\implies \log(a_m)=\log((2m)!)-2\log(m!)$$

Now, as  Alex Francisco commented, use, for large $p$, Stirling approximation
$$\log(p!)=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({p}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{12
   p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ and apply it to get $$\log(a_m)=2 m \log (2)-\frac{1}{2} \left(\log \left({m}\right)+\log (\pi
   )\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)$$ Exponentiate to get
$$a_m\approx\frac {4^m}{\sqrt{\pi m}}$$

Just a few numbers for illustration
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 m & \binom{2 m}{m} & \frac {4^m}{\sqrt{\pi m}} \\
 1 & 2 & 2.25676 \\
 2 & 6 & 6.38308 \\
 3 & 20 & 20.8470 \\
 4 & 70 & 72.2163 \\
 5 & 252 & 258.369 \\
 6 & 924 & 943.429 \\
 7 & 3432 & 3493.78 \\
 8 & 12870 & 13072.5 \\
 9 & 48620 & 49299.6 \\
 10 & 184756 & 187079.
\end{array}
\right)$$